# How can I fix the offset of the gradient to be aligned with the chart points(chart.js)?

Tags: javascript, charts, frontend, chart.js

I tried to put background colors on a line chart using linear-gradient, color by trend as you can see on the image.
But unfortunately the offset of gradient.addColorStop is not aligned with the chart.
I also tried hard-coded offsets with values of (0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1) and it also shows this issue.

```
const chartConfiguration = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['21/12', '22/12', '23/12', '24/12', '25/12', '26/12', '27/12']
    datasets: [{
      data: [20.2, 31.2, 18.4, 20.1, 15.2, 23.6, 20.1],
      label: 'example',
      fill: true
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 0
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          display: false
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          display: false
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  plugins: [{
    beforeInit: (chartInstance, options) => {
      let trend: 'positive' | 'negative' = data[0] < data[1] ? 'positive' : 'negative';
      let startPosition = 0;
      let numOfItems = 0;
      const dim = 1 / (data.length - 1);
      const gradient = chartInstance.ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 270, 0);

      for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
        const newTrend = data[i] < data[i + 1] ? 'positive' : 'negative';
        if (newTrend !== trend) {
          const endPosition = startPosition + dim * numOfItems;
          addFillColor(startPosition, endPosition, trend, gradient);
          trend = newTrend;
          startPosition += dim * numOfItems;
          numOfItems = 1;
        } else {
          numOfItems++;
        }
      }

      addFillColor(startPosition, 1, trend, gradient);
      chartInstance.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = gradient;
    }
  }]
}

const addFillColor = (startPosition: number, endPosition: number, trend: 'positive' | 'negative', gradient: CanvasGradient) => {
  const color = trend === 'positive' ? 'green' : 'red';
  gradient.addColorStop(startPosition, color);
  gradient.addColorStop(endPosition, color);
};
```

[image]

Comment: Which library are you using? `chart.js` or `echart`?

Comment: I using chart.js

Answer (score 1):

You need the `xAxis` that contains the required attributes (`left`, `right`) for creating the `gradient` together with the method `getPixelForTick` to compute the `offset` of the color stops.

Please take a look at your amended code below and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'line',
  plugins: [{
    afterLayout: chart => {
      let ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      ctx.save();
      let xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(xAxis.left, 0, xAxis.right, 0);
      let data = chart.data.datasets[0].data;
      let color;
      data.forEach((v, i) => {
        let x = xAxis.getPixelForTick(i) - xAxis.left;
        let offset = 1 / (xAxis.right - xAxis.left) * x;
        if (color) {
          gradient.addColorStop(offset, color);
        }
        if (i < data.length) {
          color = data[i + 1] > v ? 'green' : 'red'; 
          gradient.addColorStop(offset, color);
        }
      });
      chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = gradient;
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ['21/12', '22/12', '23/12', '24/12', '25/12', '26/12', '27/12'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [20.2, 31.2, 18.4, 20.1, 15.2, 23.6, 20.1],
      label: 'example',
      fill: true
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```